# Why operator ==(Object other) accepts a nullable argument?

Tags: dart

From Dart Sdk 2.12 the `Object` type should exclude null, yet `operator ==(Object other)` accepts null. (for the signature, see sdk source code of [object.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/stable/sdk/lib/core/object.dart))

Another apparent inconsistency is that it is allowed to declare a reference with both a `dynamic` and a `dynamic?` type, while in both cases a nullable object is allowed. There's a difference ?

I asked these two questions together because the signature of `==` might raise the question that with Object, as with dynamic, the suffix `?` is redundant, but in reality from the doc (e.g. [understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)) it is clear that this is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Dart language tour:

> To test whether two objects x and y represent the same thing, use the `==` operator. (In the rare case where you need to know whether two objects are the exact same object, use the [identical()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/identical.html) function instead.) Here’s how the `==` operator works:
>
> 1. If *x* or *y* is null, return true if both are null, and false if only one is null.
> 2. Return the result of the method invocation `x.==(y)`. (That’s right, operators such as == are methods that are invoked on their first operand. For details, see [Operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#_operators).)

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#equality-and-relational-operators

So the reason why `operator ==(Object other)` does not take `null` is because it is built into the language itself that comparing against `null` should always be `false` unless we compare with `null`. So you get this part of the comparison for "free", so you don't need to think about `null` input when you are writing your own `==` operator.

About `dynamic` vs `dynamic?`. As far as I know, they both represent the same so `dynamic?` is just meaningless. You can also see the analyzer and runtime will call it `dynamic` even if we check the signature of a method declared to return `dynamic?`:

```
void main() {
  print(test.runtimeType); // () => dynamic
}

dynamic? test() { }
```

Comment: Great. Unfortunately the method doc does not provide the information you reported from the language-tour, and it is not a intuitive mechanism (I don't think there are other methods with a similar non-direct invocation mechanism), at least for me that are used to Kotlin, where using `==` is equivalent to invoking `equals()` directly. In fact I have seen sometimes implement == with a preliminary null check (as an optimization, I guess, before comparing the runtimeTypes), which is actually useless. However now it is clear to me, as you said it allows to get that part of the comparison "for free"

Comment: @Mabsten I also don't think it is documented that well. I knew how it works from experience but could not remember where it was defined. But after some searching I found the clearest answer in the language guide. I am sure it is also part of the Dart language specification but it was not that easy to find a short precise paragraph here.