# Difference between Object, Dynamic and Var in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

There is a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416507/difference-between-var-and-dynamic-type-in-dart) about `dynamic` and `var` before null-safety. Then what's the `Object?` between each of them?

1. Is `Object? == dynamic`?
2. How about `var?` and `dynamic?`?
3. Any difference between `dynamic?` and `dynamic`?

I see the official [document](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) about `null-safety`, but can't find the related topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `dynamic` is a special type that *disables static type-checking*.  You can attempt to call *any* method on a `dynamic` type.  If the object turns out not to have such a method, then it will result in a runtime failure instead of a compile-time one.

   `Object?` is a base type suitable for referencing any object, including `null`.  Unlike `dynamic`, it *is* statically type-checked, so you would get compile-time failures if you attempt to call most methods on it without explicitly checking the runtime type or without performing a cast.
2. `var?` is not valid syntax. `var` is not a type; it declares a variable without explicitly specifying a type, allowing the type to be inferred.

   `dynamic?` is valid but is redundant. (See #3.)
3. Variables of type `dynamic` can already include `null`, so adding a `?` to make it nullable is redundant.  The Dart analyzer will tell you so.

Answer (score 2):

**3**: About `dynamic` vs `dynamic?`: **they are the same**.

Since `dynamic` also represents nullable types, for the compiler it is the same of `dynamic?`.

From [Why operator ==(Object other) accepts a nullable argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67400218/13303234):

> You can also see the analyzer and runtime will call it dynamic even if we check the signature of a method declared to return dynamic?:
>
> ```
> void main() {
>   print(test.runtimeType); //runtimeType of the test function: () => dynamic
> }
>
> dynamic? test() { }
> ```

In fact a hint of the dart linter reports as 'unnecessary' the use of `?` in `dynamic?` (as in `Null?`):

> The '?' is unnecessary because 'dynamic' is nullable without it. (unnecessary_question_mark).

Personally, I don't understand why `dynamic?` Is only reported by a hint (which many people, myself included, don't notice) keeping it valid as a syntax.

**1**: A variable declared with `Object?` type behaves like all other normal variables whose type is specified, such as `String?` etc. Since every class -apart `Null` (the type of `null`)- is a subclass of Object (and since in Dart there are no primitive values as opposed to objects, unlike in Java; in Dart also `null`, `int` and `bool` are objects. But forget this clarification, if you don't know Java), a variable declared with `Object?` can contain any value. But the compiler will only allow access -after a null check- to the properties of Object (`toString()`, `==()`, `runtimeType`, etc).

A variable declared with `dynamic` (or `dynamic?`, see point 3) instead allows access to any public member: the compiler will not perform any checks (unless the property begins with an underscore `_`, because in that case it is clear that it is not public); if you try to access a non-existent member you will instead have an error at runtime <sup>**Note1**</sup>. Furthermore, with `dynamic` we also renounce null safety: `dynamic` is equivalent to `dynamic?` (in practice the question mark can be considered implicit, it is as if it were always there).

**2**: using `var`, or `final` -if you want an immutable reference- without declare the type, the compiler check the value assigned to the variable (in fact the omission of the type is not allowed if the variable is not initialized immediately) and treats the variable as if it were declared with that type.

**`dynamic` at runtime**:

One use of 'dynamic' that can lead to confusion is with generic classes, because **`dynamic` *as parametric type* exists also at runtime**:

with

`dynamic obj = true;`

obj at runtime has `bool` type, but with

`List list = [bool];`

list at runtime has `List<dynamic>` type.
However, using

`var list2 = [true];`

the parametric type is inferred correctly (list2 has `List<bool>` runtimeType).

<sup>**Note1**</sup> More precisely, a invocation such as `myDynamicVariable.nonexistentMember` cause an invocation of the `noSuchMethod()` method on the object; `noSuchMethod()` can also be overridden and not throw any exception; but this is a rare practice, in Dart 2).

Comment: I'd recommend strongly that you never write `dynamic?`. It's not more explicit than `dynamic`, just more verbose and potentially confusing to the reader. There is no history of using `dynamic` to mean a non-`null` object with dynamic access.

Comment: @lrn But then why admit the `dynamic?` syntax? We are talking about one of the main keywords of the language (regardless of whether some prefer to replace it with `Object?` and explicit type casts). Personally I had thought of some possible use case, for example to distinguish a parameter that can be valued with int, bool or String, from a parameter where the same types and also null are allowed; allowed types should be made explicit by the documentation, but `dynamic?` may remark that null is among the allowed types.

Comment: However you are right, there is no general convention for using `dynamic?` (And the few occurrences in packages curated by the Dart team have been removed, from what I have seen), so I will correct the answer.